# Detached entity passed to persist with List of LatLng

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an error while saving two object with the same list : 
And I don't really understand the CascadeType and GenerationType for each classes.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity
>   passed to persist: LatLng

The test :

```
@Test
void testGetGeoArea() throws Exception {

    GeoArea geoArea = new GeoArea();
    GeoArea geoArea2 = new GeoArea();

    List<LatLng> shape = Arrays.asList(
            new LatLng(1,1),
            new LatLng(2,2),
            new LatLng(3,3));

    geoArea.setShape(shape);
    geoArea2.setShape(shape);

    geoAreaService.create(geoArea);
    geoAreaService.create(geoArea2);
```

The entities :

```
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE"})
)
@Entity
public class LatLng implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="LATLNG_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="LATITUDE")
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name="LONGITUDE")
    private double longitude;


@Entity
@Table(name = "GEO_AREA")
public class GeoArea implements GeoData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="AREA_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<LatLng> shape;
```

The service who create the entity :

```
 @Override
    public GeoArea create(GeoArea geoArea) {

        geoArea.setShape(geoArea.getShape().stream()
                .map(p -> {
                    LatLng persisted = latLngRepository.findByCoordinates(p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude());
                    if(persisted != null){
                        return persisted;
                    }
                    return p;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        return geoAreaRepository.save(geoArea);
    }
```

If you have any idea :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `GeoAreaService#create` method is not running within transaction, so the `LatLng` objects returned by `latLngRepository` are detached. Try to make the method transactional by adding @Transactional annotation (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative).

Also, since the same `LatLng` object may belong to multiple `GeoArea` objects, the relationship should be `@ManyToMany` instead of `@OneToMany`.